# Message Broker or ESB?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, esb

I have a system that relies on sockets to provide callback capabilities for a gaming system.  For failover and scalability, it is possible for a user to be attached to one socket while another user on the same team is attached to another.

When a control message comes in, I need to check how many sockets need to respond to the message; ie: if all team members are on one socket, only one socket needs to push the message to the team members.  Conversely, if team members are 'load balanced' across multiple sockets, the sockets in question need to push the message out to their respectively connected members.

Currently, I am using a polling system that queries custom DB tables which include the socket Id (GUID) as well as which members are connected to the socket.  This is joined to the message itself, so I am guranteed that each socket processes the message.

The big issue is, I LOATHE POLLING!

The big question is, what technology should I look into in order to accomplish this most efficiently?  I looked into SQL Server Dependency, but this looks like it keeps a DB connection open until a query is satisfied.

I have also entertained MSMQ, but that seems to only allow one 'subscriber', which rules out multiple interested sockets.

I am not sure about an open source ESB.  I understand the premise of ESBs, but how do I indicate that one socket processed the message, while another has not yet processed the message successfully.

Then there is the whole Message Brokering system.  Sounds eerily like a dumbed down ESB to me.

I appeal to all you enterprise architects to help me decide this quandry.

Kind Regards

Comment: "When a control message comes in, I need to check how many sockets need to respond to the message; ie: if all team members are on one socket, only one socket needs to push the message to the team members. Conversely, if team members are 'load balanced' across multiple sockets, the sockets in question need to push the message out to their respectively connected members." You're using broadcast sockets right?